# Displaying only not nullable rows in material design table

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, material-design

I've created a quiz in Angular 6 using material design component table like below. I get from the API array with four options of answers. Problem is when I want to display only two options, so then I get from the API two options where the value is `null`. In this case, it displays my table with four rows instead of two. How can I display only two rows?

```
<table mat-table *ngIf="questions" [dataSource]="questions[quizService.qnProgress].Options" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="answer" *ngIf="element !== null">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{ questions[quizService.qnProgress].Question }} </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedRowIndex == row}"
      (click)="highlight(row)"></tr>
</table>
```

This is the method that returns questions with options from API:

```
[HttpGet("/questions")]
public ActionResult<List<QuestionDetails>> GetQuestions()
{
    var result = _quizService.GetAllQuestions()
                .Select(x => new QuestionDetails
                {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    Question = x.QuestionQuiz,
                    ImageName = x.ImageName,
                    Options = new string[] { x.Option1, x.Option2, x.Option3, x.Option4 }
                })
                .OrderBy(y => Guid.NewGuid())
                .Take(10)
                .ToList();

    return result;
}
```

Maybe a better solution is to change the API method? But how? Thank you for any advice.

Comment: You can create a [pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) to filter out the `null` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Angular, but on the C# side one idea would be to change your API method to only return options that aren't null (or empty) by adding a `.Where` clause to your array assignment (this also requires `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file to use the extension method):

```
[HttpGet("/questions")]
public ActionResult<List<QuestionDetails>> GetQuestions()
{
    return _quizService.GetAllQuestions()
        .Select(x => new QuestionDetails
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Question = x.QuestionQuiz,
            ImageName = x.ImageName,
            Options = new [] { x.Option1, x.Option2, x.Option3, x.Option4 }
                .Where(option => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(option))
        })
        .OrderBy(y => Guid.NewGuid())
        .Take(10)
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Yes it is working but it necessary to add .ToArray() on the end of LINQ expression.